# Animation using HTML5 CSS3 Javascript with text to speech audio?

Tags: animation, html5-canvas, cross-browser, css-animations, watson-dialog

I'm looking for HTML5, CSS3 & Javascript framework to create small animated videos with capability of text to speech for audio which will be played in background. Framework should support cross browser support, video, audio, and canvas elements for animation.

Is any such framework available? If yes, kindly advise suggested URLs to learn?

Answer (score 3):

> Is any such framework available?

Currently there isn't any single framework that support all these features in one package (at least not readily available).

You will have to combine various frameworks which on their own provide cross-browser support (to variable degree).

Here are some examples of frameworks you can combine - there are plenty of other frameworks, but these seem to be widely used and should be stable enough for production:

**Text-to-speech**
http://responsivevoice.org/ (dual licenses)
http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/ (GPL)

**Video player**
http://videojs.com/ (Apache 2.0)

**Audio player**
https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/

**Animation**
http://createjs.com/easeljs (MIT)
https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS (different licenses, mostly for DOM)

**Video syncing**
https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js (MIT)

**Canvas element polyfill** (with some limitations*)
https://github.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas

*) In IE8 and below the canvas element isn't supported. ExCanvas allow for basic operations but cannot do things like `getImageData()` etc. There is also performance restrictions. There exists [Flash based](http://flashcanvas.net/) (see licenses) solutions as well.